# Http post request: add Header Authorization OAuth

Tags: asp.net, oauth, httprequest

I know how to add Basic's Header Authorization in asp.net:

`webreq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "BASIC " + Convert.ToBase64String(authBytes) );`

is similar for the OAuth's Header Authorization?

```
webreq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"...something..........\", oauth_nonce=\"......something............\", oauth_signature=\"......something............\", oauth_signature_method=\"......something............\", oauth_timestamp=\"......something............\", oauth_token=\"......something............\", oauth_version=\"......something............\"");
```

or how can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing authorization header for oauth token request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984463/passing-authorization-header-for-oauth-token-request)

Answer (score 0):

In **OAuth 2** you would use a bearer token so the code to add the header would be like the following

```
webreq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer -----Your token here-------");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve with:

```
string headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
               "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", oauth_signature=\"{4}\", oauth_version=\"{5}\"";

    string authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                    );

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
```

Remember to generate oauth_nonce, oauth_signatur and oauth_timestamp.